# details won't store in database

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am currently writing an application system. I'm using oracle sql developer to store the details. I'm using Microsoft visual studio 2010 to develop my system.

My question: I have a registration page, where New users need to register first. If I key in the details into the textbox provided, the details won't store in the database. If I put the details into the code, the details are stored in the database. Can someone help me to solve this problem? Thank you.

```
  SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT username, passwrd, email * from CUST_TB_REGISTER"
  SqlDataSource1.InsertCommand = "insert into cust_tb_register (username, passwrd, email) values('veni', 'asd', 'veni@yahoo.com')"
  SqlDataSource1.Insert()
```

Comment: So where is your code that gets it from the textbox and puts it into the insert statement?  Without that we can tell what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the connection string?

```
SqlDataSource1.ConnectionString = "127.0.0.0"
```